# using predict() and table() in r

Tags: r

I have used `glm` on the learning data set which without `NA`s has 49511 observations.

```
glmodel<-glm(RESULT ~ ., family=binomial,data=learnfram)
```

Using that `glm`, I tried to predict the probability for the test data set which has 49943 without `NA`s. My resulting prediction has only 49511 elements.

```
predct<-predict(glmodel, type="response", data=testfram)
```

Why is it that the result of predict is not for 49511 elements?

I want to look for false positives and false negatives. I used `table`, but it is throwing error:

```
table(testfram$RESULT, predct>0.02)
## Error in table(testfram$RESULT, predct> 0.02) : 
##  all arguments must have the same length
```

How can I get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong parameter name in `predict`. It should be `newdata=`, not `data=`. So the reason you get 49511 elements is that the default for `predict` when you don't specify new data is to output the predicted values for the data you created the model with. Hence you're getting the predicted values for your original data.